# df.schema doesn't return complete StructType of dataframe schema

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with complex nested columns. I want to convert all integer types to double types, using the scala code below:

```
def castIntToDouble(schema: StructType): Seq[Column] = {
  schema.fields.map { f =>
    f.dataType match {
      case IntegerType => col(f.name).cast(DoubleType)
      case StructType(_) =>
        col(f.name).cast(
          f.dataType.simpleString.replace(s":${IntegerType.simpleString}", s":${DoubleType.simpleString}")
        )
      case dt: ArrayType =>
        dt.elementType match {
          case IntegerType => col(f.name).cast(ArrayType(DoubleType))
          case StructType(_) =>
            col(f.name).cast(
              f.dataType.simpleString.replace(s":${IntegerType.simpleString}",s":${DoubleType.simpleString}")
            )
          case _ => col(f.name)
        }
      case _ => col(f.name)
    }
  }
}

df = df.select(castIntToDouble(df.schema):_*)
```

When I run this code, it throws an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input '.' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD'}(line 1, pos 1420)

== SQL ==
array<struct<createdAt:timestamp,sender:struct<firstName:string,lastName:string,phoneNumber:string,role:string,userId:double>,senderId:double,status:string,text:string,type:string,... 2 more fields>,issuer:struct<firstName:string,lastName:string,phoneNumber:string,role:string,userId:double>,type:string>>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

I think it is because the part `type:string,... 2 more fields` that causes the problem. I ran this code on many dataframes and it works like a charm, but not on this dataframe.

I want to know how can I somehow get an extended version of StructType from `df.schema` that prevents `n more fields`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with `... 2 more fields` is in `f.dataType.simpleString` because you are using the String representation of the types instead of the types themselves. Even if you make it work with that, the compiler won't help you find issues, and in case of failure, it will fail on execution time.

Maybe you can try to transform the schema with a recursive function and then, create a new `DataFrame` with the new schema.

Something like this:

```scala
  def castIntegerToDouble(field: StructField): StructField = field.dataType match {
    case IntegerType => StructField(field.name, DoubleType, field.nullable)
    case ArrayType(basicType, containsNull) => basicType match {
      case IntegerType => StructField(field.name, ArrayType(DoubleType, containsNull), field.nullable)
      case s: StructType => StructField(field.name, ArrayType(StructType(s.map(castIntegerToDouble))), field.nullable)
      case _ => field
    }
    case s: StructType => StructField(field.name, StructType(s.map(castIntegerToDouble)), field.nullable)
    case _ => field
  }

val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields.map(f => castIntegerToDouble(f)))
val newDf = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema)
```

Using a defined schema I think the default `Encoder` should be able to handle the casting from Integer to Double.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. The problem was actually with `simpleString`. I didn't use the code in your answer, instead I replaced `simpleString` with `catalogString`, and it solved my problem.